# Is there a way to make custom function in pandas aggregation function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

Want to apply custom function in a Dataframe
eg. Dataframe

```
    index City  Age 
0   1    A    50    
1   2    A    24    
2   3    B    65    
3   4    A    40     
4   5    B    68    
5   6    B    48
```

Function to apply

```
def count_people_above_60(age):
     **    ***                       #i dont know if the age can or can't be passed as series or list to perform any operation later
     return count_people_above_60
```

expecting to do something like

```
df.groupby(['City']).agg{"AGE" : ["mean",""count_people_above_60"]}
```

expected Output

```
City  Mean People_Above_60
 A    38    0
 B    60.33    2
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is important create new column filled by compared values converted to `integer`s, so for count is used aggregation `sum`:

```
df = (df.assign(new = df['Age'].gt(60).astype(int))
        .groupby(['City'])
        .agg(Mean= ("Age" , "mean"), People_Above_60= ('new',"sum")))
print (df)
           Mean  People_Above_60
City                            
A     38.000000                0
B     60.333333                2
```

Your solution should be changed with compare values and `sum`, but is is slow if many groups or large `DataFrame`:

```
def count_people_above_60(age):
    return (age > 60).sum()

df = (df.groupby(['City']).agg(Mean=("Age" , "mean"), 
                               People_Above_60=('Age',count_people_above_60)))
print (df)
           Mean  People_Above_60
City                            
A     38.000000                0
B     60.333333                2
```